# Max. Number of Placemarks in KML for Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I am using kml in Google Maps JavaScript API for showing Placemark in map.

KML file containing 11,031 placemarks but not showing in google map but when i reduce the Placemark 06387 it showing.

I don't know what is the problem please suggest me if any Max. Number of Placemarks limit in google map API or any alternative solution.

Comment: How **big** is your KML file?

Answer (score 1):

See:

- [original link](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport#size-and-complexity-restrictions-for-kml-rendering-in-google-maps) (no longer valid)
- [updated link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#restrictions)

(*this information used to be in the documentation, but is no longer available there, [link on archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20150906060821/https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport)*)

**Size and Complexity Restrictions for KML Rendering in Google Maps**

```
Google Maps currently has specific limitations to the size and complexity of loaded KML files. Below is a summary of the current limits:

Note: these limits are temporary and are subject to change at any time.

Maximum fetched file size (raw KML, raw GeoRSS, or compressed KMZ)  3MB
Maximum uncompressed KML file size  10MB
Maximum number of Network Links 10
Maximum number of total document-wide features  1,000
```