# County KML data that works with Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I want to display county lines on my maps.  I have found a several KMLs of converted Census data as various resolution but display.

I  created a Google Site map and uploaded several KMLs, including the CTA.kml that Google uses as an example.  The CTA (Chicago) displays w/o issue so I know my site is set up correctly.  But when I link to gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.kml(from the US Census Bureau) or cb_2014_us_county_20m.kml, nothing appears.

my belief is that the kml format is not valid for Google Maps but I do not get an error or any message.  It just doesn't appear.

I included a little test script that I know is correct since I have stolen it from Google.

If it is a KML format issue, does anyone know of a KML for US county lines?

[Link to My Site](https://sites.google.com/site/countykmltester/cta.kml)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>KML Layers</title>
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>

    function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 11,
            center: {lat: 41.876, lng: -87.624}
        });

        var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
            url: 'https://sites.google.com/site/countykmltester/gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.kml',
            map: map
        });
    google.maps.event.addListener(ctaLayer, "status_changed", function() {
       alert( "Kml Status:"+ctaLayer.getStatus());
    });
    }

</script>
<script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at the KmlStatus when the 'status_changed' event fires on the KmlLayer.  I suspect it is "DOCUMENT_TOO_LARGE".  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue ([your posted code returns "OK"](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/tftbvmnx/2/)).

Comment: I have changed the file to the one giving me issues.  I also added some Changed Status listener but when I run, it does not return anything.

Comment: [It returns "INVALID_DOCUMENT" for me](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/tftbvmnx/3/) (your code is writing to the innerHTML property of the `ctaLayer`, which doesn't do anything useful).

Comment: I am being returned an INVALID_DOCUMENT status.  Are there any valid County Line KML files?

Comment: My guess is that the file is too big, rather than invalid, but I don't know for sure.  The KmlLayer parser seems to have changed recently and is indicating documents are invalid when they aren't (according to jEdit, your file is valid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split your KML file into 3 pieces, zip each one up (to make it KMZ).  They work (status OK).  Seems that the original error message was misleading...

```
name                    | kml size  | kmz size  |
-------------------------------------------------
gz_2010_us_050_00_20m_A | 2,687,331 | 932,267   |
gz_2010_us_050_00_20m_B | 2,633,246 | 836,947   |
gz_2010_us_050_00_20m_C | 2,696,354 | 927,571   |
----- original file -----------------------------
gz_2010_us_050_00_20m   | 8,015,535 | 2,693,916 |
```

from this question on SO: [Max. Number of Placemarks in KML for Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31800897/max-number-of-placemarks-in-kml-for-google-maps):

(*this information used to be in the documentation, but is no longer available there, [link on archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20150906060821/https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport)*)

[updated link to documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#restrictions)

**Size and Complexity Restrictions for KML Rendering in Google Maps**

```
Google Maps currently has specific limitations to the size and complexity of loaded KML files. Below is a summary of the current limits:

Note: these limits are temporary and are subject to change at any time.

Maximum fetched file size (raw KML, raw GeoRSS, or compressed KMZ)  3MB
Maximum uncompressed KML file size  10MB
Maximum number of Network Links 10
Maximum number of total document-wide features  1,000
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/8Ldcvsg2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 11,
    center: {
      lat: 41.876,
      lng: -87.624
    }
  });

  var layerA = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kmz/gz_2010_us_050_00_20m_A.kmz',
    map: map
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(layerA, 'status_changed', function() {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML += "layerA:" + layerA.getStatus() + "<br>";
  })
  var layerB = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kmz/gz_2010_us_050_00_20m_B.kmz',
    map: map
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(layerB, 'status_changed', function() {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML += "layerB:" + layerB.getStatus() + "<br>";
  })
  var layerC = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kmz/gz_2010_us_050_00_20m_C.kmz',
    map: map
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(layerC, 'status_changed', function() {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML += "layerC:" + layerC.getStatus() + "<br>";
  })
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="status"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
```