# KML Layer not displaying on Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml

I'm trying to display a KML on a Google Map. The map loads perfectly, but the KML doesn't shows up at all. Also, I don't get any error messages in console.

I downloaded a .kmz file from gadm.org, unzipped it and extracted the .kml file.

Here is my code, and the URL for my KML.
http://locallocal.com/endline/mex2.kml

```
<script>
  var map;
  var src = 'http://locallocal.com/endline/mex2.kml';

  /**
   * Initializes the map and calls the function that loads the KML layer.
   */
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-19.257753, 146.823688),
      zoom: 2,
      mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    });
    loadKmlLayer(src, map);
  }

  /**
   * Adds a KMLLayer based on the URL passed. Clicking on a marker
   * results in the balloon content being loaded into the right-hand div.
   * @param {string} src A URL for a KML file.
   */
  function loadKmlLayer(src, map) {
    var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(src, {
      suppressInfoWindows: true,
      preserveViewport: false,
      map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'click', function(event) {
      var content = event.featureData.infoWindowHtml;
      var testimonial = document.getElementById('capture');
      testimonial.innerHTML = content;
    });
  }
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[MYKEY]&callback=initMap">
```

Comment: Related question: [County KML data that works with Google Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35347003/county-kml-data-that-works-with-google-maps)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get Kml Status:INVALID_DOCUMENT ([link](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://locallocal.com/endline/mex2.kml)) with that KML. Your KML is too large (it is 5.8 MB), it doesn't meet this requirement from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#restrictions):

- Maximum fetched file size (raw KML, raw GeoRSS, or compressed KMZ)  3MB

I can load it with [geoxml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/mex2.kml) which doesn't have that restriction.

Or I can zip it up (make it a .kmz file), and it works (it is 1.3 MB):

[loading it as a KMZ file](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/mex2.kmz)

Answer (score 1):

If it's not invalid xml inside the kml and the kml url will download from a browser then try to rename your kml file. renaming was the only solution that worked for. and it wasn't my browser cache because I cleared that many times. It seems google must be doing some sort of caching on their end with the api.

Answer (score 0):

My friends, google maps javascript API, KML layer,  limit the KML size to 10MB.
Over 10MB, you will get invalid document status on kmllayer object.

Your KML must first load to google KML service, than return back the tiled image to you.
Therefore your KML size must less than 10MB.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#restrictions

[image]